# Show grouped observable collection in xaml view based on a property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's imagine that I have :

```
namespace Project.Common
{
    public enum FileTypeEnum
    {
        Text = 1,
        Image = 2,
        Audio = 3,
        Video = 4
    }

    public class Artifact
    {
        public long? ArtifactId { get; set; }
        public FileTypeEnum FileType { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Above is an enum for all the file types that could be. Also, an `Artifact` model. Below is an observable collection called `Artifacts` such as :

```
public ObservableCollection<Grouping<FileTypeEnum, Artifact>> Artifacts {get; set;}
```

Now, When the page loads, with dummy data I populate the list as.

```
var list = new List<Artifact>();
list.Add(new Artifact() { ArtifactId = 1, FileType = FileTypeEnum.Image, Path = String.Format(@"\img.png") });
list.Add(new Artifact() { ArtifactId = 2, FileType = FileTypeEnum.Audio,  Path = String.Format(@"\aud.mp3") });
list.Add(new Artifact() { ArtifactId = 3, FileType = FileTypeEnum.Text,  Path = "", Text = "Lorem Ipsum .." });
list.Add(new Artifact() { ArtifactId = 4, FileType = FileTypeEnum.Image,  Path = String.Format(@"img.png") });
list.Add(new Artifact() { ArtifactId = 5, FileType = FileTypeEnum.Video, Path = String.Format(@"vid.mp4") });
list.Add(new Artifact() { ArtifactId = 6, FileType = FileTypeEnum.Image,, Path = String.Format(@"img.png") });
```

Objective is to **show the observable collection in the view as grouped data, with all images under image block, audio under audio block and so on..**

*What I've tried so for* --

I use the following class to group the list based on same file type:

```
public class Grouping<T1, T2>
{
    private FileTypeEnum key;
    private IGrouping<FileTypeEnum, Artifact> group;

    public Grouping(FileTypeEnum key, IGrouping<FileTypeEnum, Artifact> group)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.group = group;
    }
}
```

so that the observable collection is as

```
var grouped = from m in list
              group m by m.FileType into Group
              select new Grouping<FileTypeEnum, Artifact>(Group.Key, Group);

this.Artifacts = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<FileTypeEnum, Artifact>>(grouped);
```

This returns all artifacts grouped together based on the key which is the file type. The problem is the `xaml` view which I am not able to render properly(as I don't know how). The so far `xaml` view as below :

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Artifacts}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding key}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path}"/>
                        </DataTemplate >
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

My understanding is to have different `<DataTemplate>` for each file type so I can show all images under 'image' heading and together, similarly, all audio blocks under an `Audio` heading. Any alternatives to my approach are most welcomed.

Comment: @dymanoid, the view can be a tree view, if you go through the objective, it will clarify that how grouping will affect the view, elements belonging to a particular file type have to be shown together

Comment: yes, but they don't come under the same heading though.

Comment: I have described about it in the last statement of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to the ungrouped collection of `Artifacts`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Artifact> Artifacts {get; set;}
...
this.Artifacts = new ObservableCollection<Artifact>(list);
```

...and perform the grouping in the view using a `CollectionViewSource` and a `GroupStyle`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding Artifacts}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="FileType" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
    <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

> Awesome! Can you please tell how I can add more data template for other file types, for ex TextBlock for Text file type which would bind to Text property and not Path

You could use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) or a `ContentControl` with data triggers:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileType}" Value="Image">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Path}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileType}" Value="Text">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Awesome! Can you please tell how I can add more data template for other file types, for ex `TextBlock` for `Text` file type which would bind to `Text` property and not `Path`

Comment: @Sajal I guess you need to use `ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector` instead of `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`.

Comment: @grek40, only if i knew how to use that, could you guide me into the right direction? Till now, I have tried to use DataTemplate trigger with the FileTypeEnum but hard luck.

Comment: @Sajal sure thing... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx. You can also use your favorite search engine for additional information, tutorials, related questions and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Make key and group in your Grouping class public. Also bind the Itemssource to group.